# How can I optimised this query since it is causing locks

Tags: sql, sql-server

Its causing locks and I need help optimising it...

```
Select o.Vehicle as [No Unit], o.Customer, o.CustomerDisplayName as Name, o.Product as Material, P.ProductName as Product,
 o.Depot as Works, a.Distance, o.CustTravelTime as [Assumed TravelTime],  o.RequiredDateTime as [Required DateTime],o.TimeWindowOrder 
 as [To Window Provided],ToWindowDateTime as [Window DateTime],o.OrderRef as [Ref No], o.OrderEntryDateTime as [Orderred DateTime], 
  o.EnteredBy, o.Instructions, o.Warnings, o.Planning, o.AllocationState as Status,o.LoadDocket as Docket, o.LoadingDateTime
 as [Commenced Loading], o.IntransitDateTime as [Completed Loading],  o.ArrivedDateTime as [Arrived Customer], o.ArrivedDateTime
 as [Commenced Unloading], o.UnloadedDateTime as [Completed Unloading], '?' as [DMS], o.CustomerOrder as CustPO, 
    o.Renegotiated, o.TurnAround, o.StockOut,  o.LateDelivery,o.LateOrder,o.StandingOrder,o.NightShift,o.modifier 
 as [Actual Modifier], t2.Net, t2.Trantype,o.PlannedDateTime, o.VehAssignedDateTime as [Published Date], 
    t2.DriverName, o.CancelledDateTime from Orders o  left outer join Product P on p.Product = o.Product 
 left outer join AuthPlantCust A on a.Customer = o.Customer and a.Plant = o.Plant --left 
 join trans T on O.orderref = t.orderref 
 outer apply ( SELECT Top 1 Docket, Trantype, DriverName, Net FROM Trans t where o.Orderref = t.Orderref AND TranType <> 'SRT' 
 ORDER BY DespatchdateTime Desc ) T2 where o.RequiredDateTime >= (@DespatchFrom) 
 and o.RequiredDateTime < (@DespatchTo) and o.Company = 'C' order by o.RequiredDateTime, o.OrderRef
```

Or advise best practices.

Comment: Use WITH (NOLOCK) for Every table.

Comment: @Yugandhar A terrible suggestion https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I am thinking of no lock and creating a view with indexes added, anything else I can do?

Comment: Using nolock is a real bad habit. You may recover dirty pages for example that might be rollbacked afterwards. Can you give us the table definitions and the query plan linked to the query ? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Also, if you wish to stabilise the query plan to a single one, I suggest you to use parameters instead of hard coded values.